# Can't import module with location set to PYTHONPATH in Python

Tags: python, python-import, python-module, pythonpath

I've checked other answers on SO as well, but they don't seem to be like mine.

So I'm playing around with imports, and I decided to put my module `custom.py` into a nested folder like this:
`/Users/alex/Desktop/Learn/mods/onemore/custom.py`

My main script file is in the following location:
`/Users/alex/Desktop/Learn/main.py`

So when I do `import custom` in `main.py`, I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'custom'`

This happens despite the fact that `/Users/alex/Desktop/Learn/mods/onemore` is in `PYTHONPATH`:

`> echo $PYTHONPATH`

`> /Users/alex/Desktop/Learn/mods/onemore`

and also the path is visible in `sys.path` (the second one):

```
> ['', '/Users/alex/Desktop/Learn/mods/onemore', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python310.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages']
```

Why can't I still import the module?

Answer (score 1):

You can import it with folder name
Ex: `from onemore import custom`

Comment: It definitely works, but I am trying to omit concrete path and folder names. I just want to go with `import custom`. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an empty  `__init__.py` file at `/Users/alex/Desktop/Learn/mods/onemore`  to call in this manner (as a regular package).

else if it's in the python path, call it as a namespace package (no need for init):

`from custom import <func-you-need>`

The standard for imports is currently from [PEP420](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/).

Comment: Honestly, that didn't explain why Python didn't find my module in my folder. Also, placing `__init__.py` file at `/Users/alex/Desktop/Learn/mods/onemore` didn't fix the situation with `import custom`. It still can't see the module